# WP_Query Pagination

Tags: wp-query, pagination

I am having problems with `pagination` on `category` page that lists posts only within a certain category. Here is my code:

What happens is the `Next` link takes to `/page/2` but the content stays the same.

```
<?php
    $id = get_cat_id($current_category);
    $my_query = new WP_Query('cat='. $id .'&showposts=2');
    while ($my_query->have_posts()) : $my_query->the_post();
?>
    <?php the_content( __( 'Continue reading <span class="meta-nav">&rarr;</span>', 'themename' ) ); ?> 
    <?php endif; ?>
<?php endwhile; ?>

<?php if (  $my_query->max_num_pages > 1 ) : ?>
    <nav id="nav-below">
        <div class="next"><?php previous_posts_link( __( '<span></span> Previous ', 'themename' ) ); ?></div>
        <div class="prev"><?php next_posts_link( __( 'Next <span></span>', 'themename' ) ); ?></div>
    </nav>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: eeyore: You need to set the 'paged' parameter yourself if you use a custom query. Is this your main query on the page? Is there a reason why you can't use and adapt the regular query?

Comment: This seems very close to [your previous question](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/5752/page-navigation-within-a-category) maybe it's best continued there for context?

Comment: @Jan - Yes, this is my main query on the page. Is there a better solution?

Comment: WordPress always executes one query while setting up the page. If you can it's better to modify this query, since then you only have to mind your specific changes and everything else (like paging) will be done by WordPress. The second part of Mike's answer does that. If you specify exactly what you don't like about the standard query, we can help you change it.

Answer (score 1):

Hi **@eeyore:**

Without being able to see the full context of your theme page I think you have at least two issues.

1. You need to use `$wp_query` instead of `$my_query` if you want `previous_posts_link()` and `next_posts_link()` to work since they assume `$wp_query`.
2. What *@Jan Fabry* mentioned; you need to capture the pagination yourself and pass it to `WP_Query` as a `'paged'` parameter.

```
$url = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
if (strpos($url,'/page/')===false)
  $paged = 1;
else 
  $paged = preg_replace('#^.*/page/([0-9]+)/.*$#','\1',$url));
$wp_query = new WP_Query('cat='. $id ."&showposts=1&paged={$paged}");
```

That said, why are you creating your own query on this page? Is it so you can set the number of posts per page to be 2?  If so, there's a much easier way and you can let WordPress handle pagination; add this to your theme's `functions.php` file:

```
add_action('pre_get_posts','yoursite_pre_get_posts2');
function yoursite_pre_get_posts2($query) {
  $query->set('posts_per_page',2);
}
```

Comment: Why do you parse the URL to get the page parameter? Why not get it from `$wp_query->get( 'paged' )` or `$wp->query_vars['paged']`?

Answer (score 0):

Is this the right way to do it? (I can't test this right):

```
<?php
    $id = get_cat_id($current_category);
    $wp_query = new WP_Query('cat='. $id .'&posts_per_page=3'.'&paged='.$paged);
    while ($wp_query->have_posts()) : $wp_query->the_post();
?>
    <?php the_content( __( 'Continue reading <span class="meta-nav">&rarr;</span>', 'themename' ) ); ?> 
    <?php endif; ?>
<?php endwhile; ?>

<?php if (  $wp_query->max_num_pages > 1 ) : ?>
    <nav id="nav-below">
        <div class="next"><?php previous_posts_link( __( '<span></span> Previous ', 'themename' ) ); ?></div>
        <div class="prev"><?php next_posts_link( __( 'Next <span></span>', 'themename' ) ); ?></div>
    </nav>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

look at this article, this might solve your problem

[Fix WordPress Pagination Problems when used with query_posts](http://www.xcellence-it.com/tips-tricks/975/fix-wordpress-pagination-problems-when-used-with-query_posts/)